# Angular5 ng-serve & ng-build

Tags: angular5

When I use ng-serve,it compiled successful,but when I use ng-build,it failed.
Why is the difference?And how can I run ng-serve & ng-build with similiar rules?
It is `npm run dev`
[dev log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uqsB.png)
and this is `npm run build` [build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7HeJ.png)

Comment: Can you show error log?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two is the AOT (Ahead Of Time) compiler setting. Serve does not use AOT compilation, so it fails to encounter many issues that build would, since the latter would use AoT.

To learn more about AoT compilation visit the following link:
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score 0):

use angularCLI to serve and build
There is huge difference between `serve` and `build`

```
ng serve
```

Serve use to start your application on a port 
will work when you have undefined variable something like that

```
ng build
```

The build is used to create an Application(dist) to deploy in the server.
But when you will it will through all error like undefined, syntax errors, tilt errors etc.